# How to convert <div> contents to png?

Tags: python, html, image, png

I am creating a `<div>` container with multiple child `<div>`s. These `div`s will contain text or images.

When the user clicks a button to save, I am sending the parent div and it's contents back to the Django server to be converted to a `.png` image then the image name is saved to the database.

The `div` can be posted back as complete HTML but needs to include any CSS attributes. I could also convert the contents to a JSON data structure. Either way, that is not the real problem but the method of posting back to the server may depend on the solution to convert that information to a `.png` image.

I want to do this server side using Python. Each `div` will have CSS giving the exact position in `px`, the size of the `div`, font, font color, etc, etc.

Given that there are multiple `div` tags within the parent container, each `div` can be treated as a layer if necessary. Then the composite layers can be made into a single `.png`. How can I achieve this with Python?

**EDIT**:
I am looking for any information on a Python library that might already be baked to do this sort of thing. There is a dual purpose in sending the `div` attributes back to the server:

1. create the image of the composite `div`s
2. save `div` attributes to the database

Comment: I wonder if it might be easier to do the PNG stuff on the client-side.  Like how Google does for their Feedback Form.

Comment: What have you tried so far? A quick google found this: https://github.com/AdamN/python-webkit2png. But I also wonder if there might just be a better way of achieving your end goal without *rendering HTML in a PNG image*.

Comment: I know it is possible. But the div properties are also saved to the database so there is a dual purpose in sending the data back to the server. Killing two birds with 1 stone.

Comment: @JacobWalker: I haven't tried anything yet because I haven't found a library in Python that is already baked to do this. :) I am aware of `html2canvas.js` and that may meet my interim needs.

Comment: I don't want to take a screen shot. I have a designer in the browser and it is only a specific `div` container that I want converted to an image.